# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.Drawing.Image' in windows application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a data grid view,in update button i wrote code like this:

```
Dim cid As Integer
        Dim dtid As Integer
        Dim cmpname As String
        Dim dtname As String
        Dim dtPhone As String
        Dim dtEmail As String
        Dim dtimage As Image


        For i As Integer = 0 To gv.RowCount - 2
            ' Dim rv = DirectCast(bSource.Current, DataRowView)
            Dim rv = DirectCast(gv.Rows(i).DataBoundItem, DataRowView)
            cid = rv.Row.Field(Of Integer)("Cid")

            dtid = rv.Row.Field(Of Integer)("dtId")
            cmpname = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("CompanyName")
            dtname = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("Department")
            dtPhone = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("Phone")
            dtEmail = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("Email")
            dtimage = rv.Row.Field(Of Image)("empimage")

            adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE CompanyMaster_tbl SET CompanyName = @CompanyName", con.connect)
            adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand("update DepartmentMaster_tbl set dtName = @dtName,dtPhone = @dtPhone,dtEmail = @dtEmail,empimage=@dtimage  where dtId=@dtid", con.connect)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cid", cid)

            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", cmpname)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtId", dtid)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtName", dtname)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtPhone", dtPhone)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtEmail", dtEmail)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtimage", dtimage)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

but i am getting error in this line
 **dtimage = rv.Row.Field(Of Image)("empimage")** :*Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.Drawing.Image'*

Comment: Exception contains the answer to your question, you have created the variable "dtimage" of Image type, you should declare this as an array of byte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure the syntax is 100% right so I'll work on that, I'm a C# programmer by trade, but this is what you need to do:

```
Using ms As New MemoryStream(Row.Field(Of Byte())("empimage"))
    dtimage = New Bitmap(ms)
End Using
```

---

To save this same `Bitmap` back to the database you'll need to do this:

```
Using ms As New MemoryStream()
    bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.MemoryBmp)

    Dim bytes(ms.Length) As New Byte()
    ms.Read(bytes, 0, ms.Length)

    ' now save that Byte() to the field in the data table
End Using
```

**NOTE:** `MemoryBmp` might not work--you may need to use something more specific. Here is a [listing of them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Syntax is almost there.  In VB.Net arrays use `()` instead of `[]` .

Comment: this time i am getting error here adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() Error: No mapping exists from object type System.Drawing.Bitmap to a known managed provider native type.

Comment: @user3106114, first of all that a completely different problem. Now you're talking about saving it. But to save it you'll need to convert the `Bitmap` back to a `MemoryStream` using the `Save` method and then get the bytes from the stream using the [`Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: sir i given code like thise: Dim md As New MemoryStream()
            dtimage.Save(md, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)
            Dim imagedata As Byte() = md.ToArray()

Comment: sir,,in your code in this line: Dim bytes As New Byte(ms.Length) showing error,type byte has no constructor

Comment: @user3106114, bear with me a little friend--I'm not a VB.NET programmer. I'm trying to declare the initial size of the byte array. If you know the syntax for it; modify it.

Comment: @user3106114, try the modified syntax.

Comment: @user3106114, alright. Well I'm not sure about the initialization syntax so you'll need to look that up; either way you need to define the initial size of the array to the `Length` of the `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 1):

`empimage` contains an array of bytes, you need to load the image from it:

```
dtimage = ImageFromBytes(rv.Row.Field(Of Byte())("empimage"))

...


Function ImageFromBytes(ByVal bytes As Byte()) As Image
    Using ms As New MemoryStream(bytes)
        return Image.FromStream(ms)
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: this time i am getting error in thise line =adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() Error: No mapping exists from object type System.Drawing.Bitmap to a known managed provider native type